# Does the Immutable.toJS operation cause a performance issue in render React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, immutable.js

I am trying to implement Immutable.js into a React component (not in the Redux but in a component state).

I want to work with an immutable data but to render in normally I should convert it into a plain js type of data.

So if I do that trick that I'm goind to show below: Does it cause any performance issue if the state will be converted on every Render iteration ?
Thanks for any information

```
export default class StepOneComponent extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);


    /**
     * state description
     * @property { object }  userSignUpFormData  -> a userSignUp data
     * @property { string }  userSignUpForm.emailValue
     * @property { string | number }  userSignUpForm.passValue
     */

    this.state = {
     immData : ImmMap({
               userSignUpFormData : ImmMap({
                emailValue : "",
                passValue : ""
               })
           });
        }
    }

...........

render() {
        const data = this.state.immData.toJS();

return (

            <h1>{ data.userSignUpFormData.emailValue }</h1>
...........
```

Comment: `.toJS` is expensive, and you don’t have to use it. Return `<h1>{data.getIn(['userSignUpFormData', 'emailValue'])}</h1>` and similar. Also, include a shallow compare in shouldComponentUpdate to avoid unneeded re-renders – this is a major reason to use Immutablejs and it’s structural data sharing. :)

Comment: Thank you so much!